# Hardware Secure Element

Tags: soc

After checking multiple suppliers and reading about HW secure elements, I would like to understand the use of this type of electronic components.

Maybe I´m wrong, but it seems a HW secure element provides a Root of Trust for a certain data. This is, the HW Secure Element assures that, for example, a private key, will only be known by the secure element itself. Is this correct?

Now, thinking about a system where a SoC generates automatically a private key and stores it in a Trust Zone, wouldn´t this be similar to a HW secure element?

Is there an alternative to HW Secure Element in a SoC?

Comment: No one can help me here?